# datetimepicker not showing up in bootstrap dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the datetimepicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
I have a bootstrap dialogbox which contains a textfield and an ID. I have exactly copied it, but my datetimepicker does not show up... Does anyone have an idea?

Javascript/HTML:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
                //Set properties
                draggable:true,
                title: cObj.title, 
                message: function (dialogItself) {
                    var form = $('<form id="createEventForm"> </form>');
                    var klantNaam = $('<input id="titleDrop" type="text" />');
                    var description = $('<textarea id="descriptionDrop"></textarea>');
                    var employee = $('<select class="form-control" id="employee">');
                    var starttime = $('<input id="starttime" type="text" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>');
                    var startTimeDiv =
                     $('<div/>', {
                        id: 'datetimepicker4',
                        class: 'input-group date',
                        html: starttime
                    });
                    var endtime = $('<input type="text" class="endtime" id="endtime"/>');
                dialogItself.setData('field-klant-naam', klantNaam);
                dialogItself.setData('field-description', description);    // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('select-user', employee);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('starttime', startTimeDiv);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('endtime', endtime);
                form.append('<label>Klant naam</label>').append(klantNaam);
                form.append('<label>Beschrijving</label>').append(description);
                form.append('<label>Medewerker</label>').append(employee);
                form.append('<label>Start tijd</label>').append(startTimeDiv);
                form.append('<label>Eind tijd</label>').append(endtime);
                  $.each(<?php echo $list?>, function(key, value) {
                   employee.append($("<option/>", {
                        value: value.key,
                        text: value.value
                    }));
                });


                return form;
                 },
 })

    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
```

CSS:

```
  #datepicker4{
        z-index: 99999;
    }
```

Comment: is this the full code? are you adding the div to DOM? are you including javascript and css files?

Comment: yes, if I add a div before my input, I get a </script> at the end of the input field in the starttime var. So I needed it to do it this way.. But if this causes the problem, because out of the dialog it works perfect

Comment: please post the full code or create a fiddle so we can know whats the issue.

Comment: Done, I have added the code that could make sense to the problem

Comment: open firebug, go to console tab and refresh the page, then post  the errors you see.

Comment: The problem here is, I do not get any errors.... I wished I got some errors, would make it more easy

Comment: please use firebug to track errors as i mentioned, did you open console tab?

Comment: I used firebug, I opened the console tab, I got no errors as I mentioned before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `datetimepicker()` on element existing in the document, in your case you are just defining the `message: function() {}` that is returned to the BootstrapDialog object, which means it's still in memory and hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

after taking a look on the documentation of BootstrapDialog it turns out that `onShow()` is invoked after the message has been added to the DOM

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
                //Set properties
                draggable:true,
                title: cObj.title, 
                onShow: function() {
                    if (!this.datetime_invoked) {
                       this.datetime_invoked = true;
                       $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
                    }
                },
                message: function (dialogItself) {
                    var form = $('<form id="createEventForm"> </form>');
                    var klantNaam = $('<input id="titleDrop" type="text" />');
                    var description = $('<textarea id="descriptionDrop"></textarea>');
                    var employee = $('<select class="form-control" id="employee">');
                    var starttime = $('<input id="starttime" type="text" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>');
                    var startTimeDiv =
                     $('<div/>', {
                        id: 'datetimepicker4',
                        class: 'input-group date',
                        html: starttime
                    });

                    var endtime = $('<input type="text" class="endtime" id="endtime"/>');
                dialogItself.setData('field-klant-naam', klantNaam);
                dialogItself.setData('field-description', description);    // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('select-user', employee);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('starttime', startTimeDiv);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
                dialogItself.setData('endtime', endtime);
                form.append('<label>Klant naam</label>').append(klantNaam);
                form.append('<label>Beschrijving</label>').append(description);
                form.append('<label>Medewerker</label>').append(employee);
                form.append('<label>Start tijd</label>').append(startTimeDiv);
                form.append('<label>Eind tijd</label>').append(endtime);
                  $.each(<?php echo $list?>, function(key, value) {
                   employee.append($("<option/>", {
                        value: value.key,
                        text: value.value
                    }));
                });


                return form;
    },
 })
```

Comment: Okey, but I still do not see my picker. I have append it to the form, and dialog, but no result...

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem, added a z-index:1151 and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your ID is different in your CSS file. In your markup you have #datetimepicker4, but in your css  #datepicker4

Try to change in the CSS and see if it appears.

Also, check if the datetime markup is appearing when you view the source in Firebug. If so, the above may fix it as its likely a z-index issue.

Comment: yes, I saw it, but thanks, I have changed it to this: 
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{
 z-index: 99999999!important;
 }

Comment: did that fix it for you?

Comment: when you view the HTML in firebug, can you see the markup for the datetimepicker at the bottom? (probably just before the </body>

Comment: <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>

Answer (score 0):

i fixed with this code:

```
onshown: function(dialogRef){

                    $('#submit_date').datepicker({
                        language: 'ja',
                        isRTL: false,
                        //autoclose: true,
                    });
                },
```